# Find the following limit. (2 variables).

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{|y|}\sin^3(x)}{(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}}$$

My thoughts and work: 
First of all I multiplied and dividing by $x^3$, so I can get rid of the $\sin^3x$. 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^3} \frac{\sqrt{|y|}x^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}}$$
Now I know the left fraction goes to $1$. 
And by intuition, I can see that the right fraction goes to $0$, since the power of the numerator is $3.5$. and of the denominator $3$. 
But I'm struggling of how to prove it mathematically. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think polar coordinates would be helpful here

Comment: @StephenDonovan I will give it a try! totally forgot about them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\left| \dfrac{\sqrt{|y|} x^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}}\right|\leq \dfrac{\sqrt{|y|}|x|(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}}\leq \dfrac{\sqrt{|y|} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}} = \sqrt{|y|}\to 0 \quad(x,y \to 0))
$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy 's bound is nicer but I will leave this one for pedagogical purposes.

Answer (score 8):

$$\frac {|x^{3}|\sqrt {|y|}} {(x^{2}+y^{2})^{1.5}} \leq \frac {|x^{3}|\sqrt {|y|}} {(x^{2})^{1.5}}=\sqrt {|y|} \to 0.$$

Comment: Thanks alot! I've got 2 questions, when you removed $y^2$, and then divided by $x^3$. 1) How did you deal with the absolute value? (didn't quite get if you removed it or added or just it doesn't matter). 2) when you divided by $x^3$, that doesn't hold when $x=0, y\to 0$, should I just check it alone in the limit to show it's $0$? or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 5):

With $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r \sin t$ we get

$$\left| \dfrac{\sqrt{|y|} x^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}}\right| \le \frac{\sqrt{r}r^3}{r^3}= \sqrt{r}.$$